# A sorrowful letter from a friend

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Although you know me well,

You never gave me a name.

I greet you cheerfully every single day,

Yet your dull reply is always the same.

You may hate or love me,

But you only ever whine,

For often when you need me,

I am not there in time.

I do more for you than you could imagine,

Every single day, I am there.

And yet for all of this, in the end,

You leave me without a care.

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who am I?

> You are a computer(probably systems we use for work).

Although you know me well,

You never gave me a name.

> we know the system ,it has a brand name, but we never gives a name.

I greet you cheerfully every single day,

Yet your dull reply is always the same.

> Always shows welcome message.(but we don't really care)

You may hate or love me,

But you only ever whine,

> true for most workstation systems.

For often when you need me,

I am not there in time.

> System hangs/Network fail etc?

I do more for you than you could imagine,

> true.

Every single day, I am there.

> System is always there.

And yet for all of this, in the end,

You leave me without a care.

> we leave the system when we buy a new one or when we switch jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a

> mirror

?

Although you know me well

> I meet you (mostly) ever day

I greet you cheerfully every single day

> Ok, mine does not, but let's go on

Yet your dull reply is always the same.

> Fair enough

You may hate or love me

> True, depends on what you show me

But you only ever whine

> Who does not?

For often when you need me,
I am not there in time

> This may be adressed to a certain gender

I do more for you than you could imagine

> You reflect me, even if I imagine a different apperance

Every single day, I am there

> That's your destiny

And yet for all of this, in the end,
You leave me without a care.

> Maybe, at least I should think of a name for you...

Comment: I like your thinking but unfortunately not the answer! 
On a plus your answer does provide good reason for one to always be positive with self image though, because what YOU see in a mirror is a great reflection on your life - and so many of us really do whine rather than embracing what is there!